# Clojure: Difference between defrecord and defschema

Tags: clojure, compojure, compojure-api

I am new to clojure. I want to fetch x records with fields from database and want to insert records into database. Which once should I use between `defrecord` and `defschema` in this scenario?

Are those the same?

Comment: If I am not wrong. defschema is derived from schema.core(clojure script library). Both defschema and defrecord are different. I should use defrecord in this scenario.  Please correct me If I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`defschema` and `defrecord` do not refer to database schema ("shape of database") nor to records (i.e., rows in relational DBs).

[Schema](https://github.com/plumatic/schema) is a library for describing the shape of your data, and validating whether some data conforms to this shape. It is similar to the more recent [clojure.spec](https://clojure.org/about/spec). Clojure *Records* are custom datatypes, which look a bit like Java-classes.

It is easy to be tempted to write "Object Oriented" DB communication with Records for each entity. However, all database contains is data, which is just lists, maps, sets, and some basic data types. I suggest you keep your data in built-in Clojure data structures, ready at hand, and don't hide it in unnecessary abstractions. (Side note: your DB **component**, instead of DB entity, may very well be a Clojure Record. For example, lifecycle management with [Component](https://github.com/stuartsierra/component) uses Records.)

A good place to start would be [Honey SQL](https://github.com/jkk/honeysql), which allows you to build SQL queries as Clojure data structures. You get back data and can operate on that data with the full might of Clojure.

Then, when you are comfortable with "laying all your data open (without *encapsulation*)", go and describe the shape of your data, what is valid and what is not. `clojure.spec` is a powerful tool for that.